# Canada Super Visa

Tags: visas, canada

A friend's parents are in Canada on a Super Visa, so they are allowed to stay for 2 years as this is the initial year.

Now, a year has passed and they want to visit  the USA or India. When they return, will they be able to complete the 1 year (which is the balance of the initial 2 years) or will they be only allowed to stay for 6 months?

Answer (score 2):

The 2 year provision is only for the initial visit. Once you exit your visa is still valid, but you can stay for up to 6 months on each visit.

> The Super Visa is a multi-entry visa that provides multiple entries for a period up to 10 years. The key difference is that the Super Visa allows an individual to stay for up to two years on initial entry into Canada, while a 10-year multiple entry visa would only have a status period for each entry of six months only.

From: http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=426&top=16